# What is the meaning of : Warning in do.call(.f, args, envir = .env) : "what" must be a function or character string

Tags: r, apache-spark, tidyverse, databricks, azure-databricks

This is the exact message:

```
Warning in do.call(.f, args, envir = .env) :
  'what' must be a function or character string
```

Working in an Azure Databricks environment for data processing using R, spark and the tidyverse.
This message appears even when running an empty command cell.

- Could this be coming from the cluster configuration in Databricks UI?
  I am loding the following libraries:

```
# library(sparklyr)
# library(lubridate)
# library(dplyr)
# library(purrr)
# library(httr)
# library(jsonlite)
# library(tidyr)
# library(arrow)
# library(stringr)
# library(DBI)
# library("readxl")
```

and I use

```
# if(!require(*library*)){
#   install.packages(*"library"*)
# }
```

Is this something I should worry about with this warning or that I should be checking? I don't understand the warning and could not find the right documentation on google.

Comment: Yes.  You should worry about the warning sufficiently to reassure yourself it is not important.  Or to fix it if it is.  A piece of code your are running (we can't say what, because you haven't given us anything useful) is calling.  `do.call`.  `do.call` requires, as the warning suggests, a character or function in its (first) `what` argument.  It's not getting it.  What it's getting, and whether the difference is important, I cannot say.  But best practice would be to fix the problem even if it *apparently* has no consequences.

Comment: Maybe I did not mention it explicitly, but this warning was coming out of running that code, just loading libraries, even when running only a cell with a comment line, no script. So it seems the issue was with the environment rather than the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me if some genius package maintainer has masked (~overwritten) something important or uses a (function's) name rather than a character string in `do.call`.

You can reproduce the issue like so.

```
do.call(rbind, list())  ## using the name works as expected
# NULL
```

Now let's mask `rbind`

```
rbind <- 1
do.call(rbind, list())  ## using the name fails
# Error in do.call(rbind, list()) : 
#   'what' must be a function or character string
```

Voilá.

It's safer to use the character string here, which won't fail.

```
do.call('rbind', list())
# NULL

rm(rbind)  ## unmask `rbind`.
```

The **solution** is tricky, since you're loading a ton of libraries. You could do the following though:

1. Close R-session, if working with RStudio, uncheck *Tools > Global Options > General > Restore .RData* (maybe the uncheck already solves the issue!)
2. Check `Renviron.site` and `Renviron.site` files for unusual entries (can be found in the `/etc/R/` folder on Linux), alternatively maybe start a `R -vanilla` session
3. Start a fresh R session
4. Load each `library` one by one until the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

This answer is of very limited scope, but wanted to share.

I was getting this error in Databricks as well when I loaded the whole tidyverse, but I don't get it when I just load dplyr and ggplot2.